# SQL: Replicated transactions are waiting for the next Log back up or for mirroring partner to catch up

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactional-replication

I have two SQL Server DB instances on the same machine with one hosting a replica of the other. In addition, I have transaction replication setup for all tables on the main instance to the replica. I have verified that the log reader and associated agents are all running. However, one of the log reader agent says "Replicated transactions are waiting for the next Log back up or for mirroring partner to catch up". I have done a transactional log backup to trigger it but to no avail; tried deleting the subscriber and publisher and recreating it again…but still end up with this message.

Comment: off topic but I have to ask why have the two instances on the same machine? I'd assume they are at least not using local or the same storage, but there will still be memory and cpu contention and hardware failure liabilities (making this not a DR). Just curious is all.

Comment: I hear you. I inherited this legacy system and am not a fan of the implementation. Just trying to get the subscribers established and the replication working again.

Comment: no sweat. I'd post on dba.stackexchange.com -- the DBA gurus play over there